# how to display date as feb-04-2012 instead of 02/04/2012 in uidatepicker

Tags: php, jquery-ui-datepicker

My UI date picker shows the date as mm/dd/yy format I need to change this as monthname-dd-yy
i.e.

```
04/02/2012 as march-02-2012
```

But I don't know how?

Does anyone know this?

Please advice

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `dateFormat` option to the datepicker

```
$('#picker').datepicker({
  dateFormat:'MM-dd-yy'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the format string `MM-dd-yy`:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy' });
```

See [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate).

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Init
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "MM/dd/yy" });

// Setter after init
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "MM/dd/yy" );
```

Supported formats:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate